# PHP Singleton Class - Fatal error: Call to private MyObject::__construct()

Tags: php, class, model, singleton

**Singleton Class:**

```
<?php

class db_singleton
{
    const ORACLE_HOST = "SOMEIP";
    const ORACLE_USER = "validuser";
    const ORACLE_PASS = "validpass";
    const ORACLE_DB = "SOMEIP/DBNAME";

    private static $instance; // stores the oci_* instance

    private function __construct() { } // block directly instantiating

    private function __clone() { } // block cloning of the object


    public static function call()
    {

        // create the instance if it does not exist
        if(!isset(self::$instance))
        {
            // the ORACLE_* constants should be set to or
            //  replaced with your db connection details
            self::$instance = oci_connect(self::ORACLE_USER, self::ORACLE_PASS, self::ORACLE_DB);
            if(self::$instance->connect_error)
            {  
                throw new Exception('Oracle connection failed: ' . self::$instance->connect_error);
            }
        }
        // return the instance
        return self::$instance;
    }


        public function __destruct() {
        oci_close($instance);
    }

    public function queryresult($query)
    {

            $result_set_array =array();
            $this->stmt = oci_parse($this->con, $query);
            oci_execute($this->stmt);

            while($row=oci_fetch_array($this->stmt,OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS))
            {

                $result_set_array[] = $row;
            }
            oci_free_statement($this->stmt);
            return $result_set_array;

    }
}
?>
```

When I try using `singleton` class with below code, it works perfect and fetch results.

```
$conn = db_singleton::call();
$stid = oci_parse($conn, 'SELECT * FROM somevalid_table');
oci_execute($stid); 
while($result=oci_fetch_array($stid,OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS))
  { 
   $result_set_array[] = $result;
 }
```

Now, when I try extending my class using model, it throws exception

```
class Myclass Extends db_singleton{

public function someModel()
    {

        $result = parent::queryresult(" select * from somevalid_table");
        return $result;
    }   
}
```

**Exception:**

```
 Fatal error: Call to private db_singleton::__construct() from context 'someController'
```

I know that class cannot be instantiated having private constructor.  **__construct()** functions are always called when an object is instantiated, so trying to do something like **$x = new MyObject()** will cause a fatal error with a private construction function.

I am using  `Singleton` classes to prevent direct instantiation of an object. How can I overcome issue ? What would be the best solution ?

Thanks.

Comment: Add an empty constructor to your child class. This will override the parent class constructor which is private.

Comment: And will it affect singleton pattern ?

Comment: If you want true singleton behavior don't extend the singleton class.

Comment: So how can I use it for any model or class ?

Comment: $instance = db_singleton::call(); within your model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**PHP Class Script:**

```
class db_singleton
{
    const ORACLE_USER = "validuser";
    const ORACLE_PASS = "validpass";
    const ORACLE_DB = "SOMEIP/DBNAME";

    private static $instance = null; // stores the oci_* instance

        // private constructor
        private function __construct() { } // block directly instantiating

    private function __clone() { trigger_error('Clone is not allowed.', E_USER_ERROR); } // block cloning of the object

    public static function getInstance()
    {

        // create the instance if it does not exist
        if(!isset(self::$instance))
        {
            // the ORACLE_* constants should be set to or
            //  replaced with your db connection details
                        self::$instance = oci_connect(self::ORACLE_USER, self::ORACLE_PASS, self::ORACLE_DB);
            if(self::$instance->connect_error)
            {  
                throw new Exception('Oracle connection failed: ' . self::$instance->connect_error);
            }
        }
        // return the instance
        return self::$instance;
    }

    public static function queryresult($query)
    {

            $result_set_array =array(); 
            $stmt = oci_parse(db_singleton::getInstance(), $query);
            oci_execute($stmt);

            while($row=oci_fetch_array($stmt,OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS))
            {
                            $result_set_array[] = $row;
            }
            oci_free_statement($stmt);
            return $result_set_array;

}
```

Now to prevent `Fatal error: Call to private db_singleton::__construct()`, I have added an `empty constructor` to my `child class` which is `model` class in my case. This will override the parent class constructor which is private.

```
class Myclass Extends db_singleton{

    public function __construct() {}

    public function someModel(){

            $result = parent::queryresult(" select * from somevalid_table");
            return $result;
    }   
}
```

Hope it helps someone.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`$x = new MyObject()` will never work if your constructor is private in that class because `__construct()` is the first method that is invoked on object creation.

```
Create a public method
/**
 * Singleton class
 *
 */
final class UserFactory
{
    /**
     * Call this method to get singleton
     *
     * @return UserFactory
     */
    public static function Instance()
    {
        static $inst = null;
        if ($inst === null) {
            $inst = new UserFactory();
        }
        return $inst;
    }

    /**
     * Private ctor so nobody else can instance it
     *
     */
    private function __construct()
    {

    }
}
```

To use:

```
$fact = UserFactory::Instance();
$fact2 = UserFactory::Instance();

$fact == $fact2;
```

But:

```
$fact = new UserFactory()
```

Comment: Yes, so whats the proposed solution ?

Comment: You have to create a static method that retruns the instance

Comment: `$x = db_singleton::Instance();` this works for me as I stated in question. But when I try extending class in my model, it does not.

Comment: You can also use the same thing in another class to get an instance